# R - Corrplot() correlation matrix has question marks in the grid. How to understand the matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, plot, correlation, r-corrplot

I am trying to create a correlation matrix of the variables from IMDB movie prediction dataset from kaggle. When I try to plot the correlation matrix I get the following question marks in the matrix.

[image: Correlation matrix]

All the variables are numeric. How do i understand the question marks?

```
numeric_col <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
movie_numeric <- df[, numeric_col]
Correlation <- cor(movie_numeric)
corrplot(Correlation)
```

Comment: From `?corrplot`: 'na.label - Label to be used for rendering NA cells. Default is "?".'  See also the [introductory documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html).

Answer (score 9):

Like @neilfws said in his comment - `NA` values are represented by question marks.

You can try to avoid having `NA` values by using only pairwise-complete observations when computing the correlation matrix:

```
Correlation <- cor(movie_numeric, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```