# correlation diagram with 3 variables doesn't work on R

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

I am trying to plot a diagram of correlation with corrplot, between age, time passed in the firm, and wage. However, I get the following diagram with question marks everywhere : how can I solve this problem and get a diagram I can work with ? [image: Here is an image of the plot i get]

```
 library(corrplot)

 df1$age = as.numeric(df1$age)
 df1$time_passed = as.numeric(df1$time_passed)
 df1$wage = as.numeric(df1$wage)

 corrplot(cor(df1))
```

Here is the structure of my dataset :

```
structure(list(age = c(24, 33, 53, 32, 38, 21), time_passed = c(0, 
3, 4, 0, 2, 0), wage = c(2605, 4931, 11123, 3750, 6180, 858.31
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: When I run your code, there are no question marks? Did you restart your environment and clean ?

Comment: According to this post [Corrplot question marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55034995/r-corrplot-correlation-matrix-has-question-marks-in-the-grid-how-to-underst), this happens when you have `NA` in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any `NA` like mentioned in this post: [R - Corrplot() correlation matrix has question marks in the grid. How to understand the matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55034995/r-corrplot-correlation-matrix-has-question-marks-in-the-grid-how-to-underst). Also check if you don't have any overwriting variables, so try with a clean environment. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(corrplot)
#> corrplot 0.92 loaded
df1 <- structure(list(age = c(24, 33, 53, 32, 38, 21), time_passed = c(0, 
                                                                       3, 4, 0, 2, 0), wage = c(2605, 4931, 11123, 3750, 6180, 858.31
                                                                       )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

df1$age = as.numeric(df1$age)
df1$time_passed = as.numeric(df1$time_passed)
df1$wage = as.numeric(df1$wage)

corrplot(cor(df1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>